# How to add an instance of a class into an array of another class (Ruby)

Tags: arrays, ruby, class, object, instance

I have two files in my directory, one which is `garage.rb` & another called `car.rb`.

`car.rb` file just holds a car object:

```
class Car
end
```

`garage.rb` file is as follows:

```
require 'car.rb' #Makes car class accessible in garage.rb

class Garage
  def initialize
    @capacity = []
  end

  attr_accessor :capacity

end
```

When I make a new instance of a `car` by calling `car = Car.new`, how do I put `car` object in the `@capacity` array my default?

Essentially, whenever I call `car = Car.new`, I want `car` to be put in the `@capacity` array instantly.

I understand that I could make a function like so:

```
def add_car_to_garage(car)
  capacity << car
end
```

But, I want the car to start in the garage when it is created, so I don't want a method to add it to the array, I just want it to automatically start there when the instance of `car` is created.

Any advice would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `ObjectSpace` module with [each_object](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/ObjectSpace.html#method-c-each_object) method inside your `Car` class to define method to keep track for each living instances, like this:

```rb
class Car

  def self.all
    ObjectSpace.each_object(self).to_a
  end
end
```

```rb
require_relative 'car' # Makes car class accessible in garage.rb 
                                                                 
class Garage                                                     
  def initialize                                                 
    @capacity = Car.all                                          
  end                                                            
                                                                 
  attr_accessor :capacity                                        
end
```

```rb
car1 = Car.new        
car2 = Car.new        
car3 = Car.new        
                      
garage = Garage.new   
                      
print garage.capacity   # => [#<Car:0x0000563fa14128c8>, #<Car:0x0000563fa1412918>, #<Car:0x0000563fa1412990>]
```

Also note, I have used `require_relative` to include `car.rb` class which is in the same directory.

---

Edit for comment question and Cary Swoveland suggestion:

```rb
class Car
end
```

```rb
require_relative 'car' # Makes car class accessible in garage.rb 
                                                                 
class Garage                                                     
  def initialize; end                                            
                                                                 
  def capacity                                                   
    ObjectSpace.each_object(Car).to_a                            
  end                                                            
end                                                              
                                                                 
car1 = Car.new                                                   
garage = Garage.new                                              
car2 = Car.new                                                   
                                                                 
print garage.capacity # => [#<Car:0x000055d7bd236a00>, #<Car:0x000055d7bd236b18>]
```

Also note, I removed `attr_accessor :capacity`, since you don't need it in this case.

Comment: Thank you. With the code you mentioned, if you called the objects in this order:

`car1 = Car.new`
`garage = Garage.new`
`car2 = Car.new`

Would you have any ideas on how to add car2 to that same array by itself whilst the `garage` object is already made? (Apologies, totally new to classes haha)

Comment: Because when you call `garage = Garage.new`, ruby [initializes](https://ruby-doc.org/docs/ruby-doc-bundle/UsersGuide/rg/objinitialization.html) variables in initialize method at the time of object creation, therefore it does not know about the existence of `car2`. So, you can define capacity as a separate method and call it whenewer you want.

Comment: I edited the answer to include an example.

Comment: It was my understanding that the question asked what the OP requested in his/her first comment above. Regarding your update why don't you just write `def capacity; ObjectSpace.each_object(self); end` (and remove `Car::all`)?

Comment: Note that [ObjectSpace#each_object](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/ObjectSpace.html#method-c-each_object) may include objects that have been marked for garbage collection but not yet collected. For example, `c = Car.new #=> #<Car:0x00007fe59608d800>; g = Garage.new; #<Garage:0x00007fe59591b108>; g.capacity #=> [#<Car:0x00007fe59608d800>]; c = nil # (c to be garbage collected); g.capacity #=> [#<Car:0x00007fe59608d800>] (will be [] after garbage collection)`.

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out, Cary. I think it will be absolutely fair if the OP will change the marked answer. I also edited the answer to include your suggestion from the previous comment.

Answer (score 0):

The collection of instances of `Car` should be kept and maintained by that class and made available to other classes as needed. That can be done as follows.

```
class Car
  @cars = []

  class << self
    attr_reader :cars
  end

  def initialize
    self.class.cars << self
  end
  
  def self.remove_car(car)
    cars.delete(car)
  end
end
```

```
class Garage
  def self.cars
    Cars.cars
  end
end
```

The creation of the class `Car` initializes the class instance variable `@cars` and creates a getter for it, `Cars::cars`, the latter by invoking `attr_reader` on `Car`'s singleton class.

Let's create a car:

```
car1 = Car.new
  #=> #<Car:0x00007fcf3db76fd8>
```

Then

```
Car.cars
  #=> [#<Car:0x00007fcf3db76fd8>]
Garage.cars
  #=> [#<Car:0x00007fcf3db76fd8>]
```

Create another car.​

```
car2 = Car.new
  #=> #<Car:0x00007fcf3db5c9a8>
```

Then

```
Car.cars
  #=> [#<Car:0x00007fcf3db76fd8>, #<Car:0x00007fcf3db5c9a8>]
Garage.cars
  #=> [#<Car:0x00007fcf3db76fd8>, #<Car:0x00007fcf3db5c9a8>]
```

Now remove a car.

```
Car.remove_car(car1)
  #=> #<Car:0x00007fcf3db76fd8>
```

Then

```
Car.cars
  #=> [#<Car:0x00007fcf3db5c9a8>]
Garage.cars
  #=> [#<Car:0x00007fcf3db5c9a8>]
```

---

To make the class instance variable `@cars` available to instances of `Garage` add a simple instance method:

```
class Garage
  def all_cars
    self.class.cars
  end                                                            
end
```

```
Garage.new.all_cars
  #=> [#<Car:0x00007fcf3db5c9a8>]
```

---

In `Car`

```
class << self
  attr_reader :cars
end
```

can alternatively be written

```
singleton_class.public_send(:attr_reader, :cars)
```